# Add a new property in a JSON Object

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a Tyescript project in which I have a class with a JSON Object in which I want to add a a new property.

This is my current Object:

```
let files = [    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.csv' },
                 { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_INS.csv' },
                 { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_BRA.csv' } ];
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
let files = [    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.csv', exists: 1, error: 0 },
                 { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_INS.csv', exists: 0, error: 0 },
                 { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_BRA.csv', exists: 0, error: 1 } ];
```

This is what I am doing:

```
files.push({ exists: 1, error: 0 }, { exists: 0, error: 0 }, { exists: 0, error: 1 });
```

This is the error it returns:

*Cannot assign an argument of type "{exists: number; error: number;}" to the parameter of type "{codCountry: string; fileName: string;}".
The object literal can only specify known properties and 'exists' does not exist in type' {codCountry: string; fileName: string; } '*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. As you do not explicitely define a type for your array item, typescript deduces the type from the existing items. Thus your files has the following type

   `let files: {codCountry: string, fileName: string }[] = ...`

   To allow to add additional properties to your objects, you have to define them in the type.
2. You cannot use `Array.push` to add new properties to existing items in the array. `push` will add new items to the end of the array. If you want to add properties to existing items, you have to iterate over the array and add the properties to each item separately.

So let's first define an appropriate type, which will have `exists` and `error` as an optional property.

```
let files: {codCountry: string, fileName: string, exists?: number, error?: number }[] = [
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.csv' },
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_INS.csv' },
    { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_BRA.csv' }]
```

Then we define the new data

```
let additional = [{ exists: 1, error: 0 }, { exists: 0, error: 0 }, { exists: 0, error: 1 }];
```

And finally, go over the array and add the new properties:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  files[i].exists = additional[i].exists;
  files[i].error = additional[i].error;
}
```

You can also use `Array.forEach()` to iterate over the array

```
files.forEach((file, i) => {
  file.exists = additional[i].exists;
  file.error = additional[i].error;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Typescript is inferring the type of your array as `{codCountry: string; fileName: string;}[]`.

As there are no `exists` or `error` properties on this inferred type, and the objects you are trying to push are missing `codCountry` and `fileName` properties, you can't push those items into that array.

You could make a type `TFile` with optional properties and use it to explicitly type `files` when you declare it.

```
type TFile = {
  codCountry: string;
  fileName: string;
  exists?: number;
  error?: number;
};

let files: TFile[] = [
  { codCountry: "CO", fileName: "CO_SER.csv" },
  { codCountry: "CO", fileName: "CO_INS.csv" },
  { codCountry: "CO", fileName: "CO_BRA.csv" },
];

const extraFields = [
  { exists: 1, error: 0 },
  { exists: 0, error: 0 },
  { exists: 0, error: 1 },
];

const newFiles = files.map((file, i) => {
  const {exists, error} = extraFields[i];
  return {
    ...file,
    exists,
    error,
  };
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAYgSwDZwLzAN4ChSgDGA9gCYDCxArgHZgBOEAXMAM4PI0DmA3PgcABmaGADkAhgFsYLdvU69+BGAA9k7VgH4WNKpIBGMenwHAj9YvW3BdBoydABfPkuDowQkaxZIRAbQBdYCw-VxBsYBIKajpGFgAicgB5eIAaT3QJaQTkgH0AZQBRACUAOkJWADd44EdUsJxIskpaBmZgRJT04UypGQ68gElRfPKqmrqGiKiW2PbOtIyxPpyk3IAhYoBBMera+oIAlwISGnYzFQZxFBhUUlZg4FDTCNV1MG9gAEZ080sWAAM+ymF3enwBv3oFnogOBL1BGkBkOhLC+cNAR1wrlO5xoMAA7ih0A8sD0YKxSpJxFAABQ0snpZAASmCAD4cA0cR5sG8NMjLI5Hqorjc7qw-MhMaZ6DAwFR6DQOaYQKVVQyGiBeR8Dsq-vQdQRnK5HEy+EA)

Comment: This adds another element to me, what I want is to add those properties inside the element. This is what I have achieved: ```[ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.csv' },
  { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_INS.csv' },
  { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_BRA.csv' },
  { exists: 1, error: 0 },
  { exists: 0, error: 0 },
  { exists: 0, error: 1 } ]```

Comment: While this will compile and run, it's probably not what OP really wants. As I understand the question, he wants to add the `exists` and `error` properties to the items already existing in the array ...

Answer (score -1):

You are adding new elements to the "files" array, not adding the new properties to the objects in array.

You can do something like:

```
files.forEach(object => {
    object.error = 1 //or 0
    object.exists = 1 //or 0
})
```

Comment: This will work in plain JS. But as TS ensures compiletime type safety this won't work. Futhermore, different elements in the array should probably get different values (especially the values currently given to `push`)